# How to correctly structure classes and methods in more complex OOP overview

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to understand advanced PHP OOP principles, having programmed procedural Php for years. I wondered if there is a rule of thumb for how best to group functions in to classes and how to plan which classes to abstract / extend? If not, could you recommend any advanced reading that might help.

I have read a few (self-defined) 'advanced' OOP tutorials. The examples have taught me the basics for how to create very loosely coupled objects with very minimal attributes defined in heavily abstracted classes. I've also read other (bad) tutorials which basically turn functions in to methods and encapsulate them in classes - and I know they are not written well so don't want to emulate them.

However, I'm not clear how to decide which classes to build my project around - I'm not sure if I should think first about the macro features of an application or about the frequently carried out actions.

Take for example a website in which:
 - Users can sign up and have different privileges depending on user
   levels
 - Users can edit their user details, upload photos, sign up to a mailing list and join groups with other users
 - Admins can create new sections in the site within 5 different module areas
 - Users can post articles and comments within these different distinct sections

1) If admins can create a sections within 5 different module areas (single, double and triple level blogs, forum, poll) should I think in terms of 1 class per module?

OR 2) should I generate a new 'class' for every new section an admin creates?

OR 3) Users are the central focus of the entire site - Users interact with the modules and the sections - so do I create a large user class containing insert, edit, delete methods?

Following on from that, where is best to put the methods?

a) I'm going to need to freuently use an SQL insert clause - I'll need to insert to the user table when someone signs up, insert to the groups table when someone makes or joins a group, or posts an article, comment or IM - so I'll use a method like the following... but should this be nested inside all of the other classes, or repeated in each of the module classes?

```
    // runs a sql query
    public function runQuery($qry) {
        $result = $this->mysqli->query($qry);
        return $result;
    }
```

Likewise things like emailing the user multiple times - when they sign up to activate their account, when they join a mailing list, if they forget their password... So I imagine I would need a method for that.

As you can see, I'm confused as to to which class I should I put my methods in, and which classes to build my site around.

I'm fairly sure that I shouldn't need to think through 'all' my features before I start, as that wouldn't work well with an Agile development environment where users might suggest new features, so I'm hoping there is a relatively simple bit of guidance you might be able to offer me.

This is just one of many examples of sites I've previously coded procedurally and now want to start thinking about in OOP terms, so any pointers would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Well it is plain that you are thinking quite deeply and with good intentions. A person can get quite carried away trying to come up with the perfect OOP design. This is something that takes years of experience, practice and good judgement. My best advise it to prototype and find out what works best for your individual problem.

Comment: take help of any framework(few of them are cakephp, zend , Yii)in php, it might give you a better idea

Comment: i think you should categorize your functions based on your needs and place common functions inside a base class and then extend from it.

Comment: You might be over-thinking <i>the perfect OOP design pattern</i>. I suggest writing a framework until you are impressed with it.

Comment: This is a nice question. Just too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very difficult to come with proper solution without understanding what do you really want. When you are facing a problem/feature request you have to design application. Everything depends on feature/issue.

There are many different solutions, and each one is good for specific case. I cannot answer your question without deep understanding what do you want to tackle. The only think that I can advice :
 - KISS - Keep it simple Stupid
 - SOLID Principles, especially Single Responsibility Rule - each class should be responsible for only one thing. For example if you have User object, you should have at least three classes. UserEntity or UserDomain - simple representation of object, Repository/Storage for that user that brings you the basic operations on given user (CRUD - Create,Read,Update,Delete), and then you should have a module,service that handles the interactions, (for example between different users). The less one class know the better.

The good way to start is reading at least a little bit about design patterns, SOLID, maybe about DDD (Domain Driven Design). Also I can suggest watching CleanCoders. Uncle bob has very good (in my opinion) video tutorials about software development.

I used to say, that if you want to do something correctly, you have to do it twice. At first approach you don't know what you can expect, you cannot come with best solution without deep understanding what you're facing.
When I'm writing a piece of code, for example a class, I'm always writing it at least two times. Almost each part of class is refactored during development in order to remove duplicated code, improve perfomance. It's very rare when developer comes with perfect solution at first time.